# Trainer acts as if it's training from scratch

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

I'm training a model with a huggingface trainer and I specified the checkpoint folder for the `resume_from_checkpoint` parameter.
However, when it continues to train, it still saves the checkpoints with the names corresponding to the first save steps (e.g. `checkpoint-4` even though `resume_from_checkpoint` should start from `checkpoint-4096`). The progress bar shows all the `max_steps` as well, even though I don't want it to start from the beginning.

Is this a common problem? How do I fix this?

I save my training arguments in a yaml file:

```
training_args:
   learning_rate: !!float 1e-4
   do_train: true
   per_device_train_batch_size: 8
   per_device_eval_batch_size: 8
   logging_steps: 1024
   output_dir: /path/to/training_output/
   overwrite_output_dir: False
   remove_unused_columns: False
   save_strategy: steps
   evaluation_strategy: steps
   save_steps: 1024
   load_best_model_at_end: True
   warmup_steps: 100
   max_steps: 65536
   seed: 22
   resume_from_checkpoint: /path/to/checkpoint-4096
```

and then train the model by initialising a TrainingArguments object with these as **kwargs.

But the terminal displays:

```
Saving model checkpoint to /path/to/checkpoint-4
```

And the progress bar shows all the steps, even though I need it to start from step 4096.